# Using REGEX, remove a date such as March 5, 2015

Tags: php, regex, date

I am new with regex. I want to remove all the dates that match the format of `March 20, 2015` in

"March 01, 2015 to March 05, 2015 JEEBRON, LEE (NT012-003) Date In 1 Out 1 In 2 Out 2 In 3 Out 3 In 4 Out 4 In 5 Out 5 In 6 Out 6 s RequiredHrs Brers Worked Hrs OT Hrs UT 03/02/2015 6:46 am 5:42 pm 10.00 0.00 10.00 0.93 0.00 ABALA, DARLA (FC08-002) Date In 1 Out 1 In 2 Out 2 In 3 Out 3 In 4 Out 4 In 5 Out 5 In 6 Out 6 s RequiredHrs Brers Worked Hrs OT Hrs UT 03/01/2015 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00"

So far I have only found how to match the mm/dd/yyyy format. BTW I'm using this file in php

Comment: `preg_replace('~\bMarch \d{2}, \d{4}\b~', '', $str);`

Answer (score 0):

If it's not always March: 
"[A-Z][a-z]{4} ([0-9]|([0-9]{2}), [0-9]{4}"

(Without the quotes)